# MySQL で UNION ALL の結果に、インクリメントする ID カラムを追加したい

Tags: mysql, sql

### ■ 現状SQL

```sql
SELECT Y.id, Y.hoge, Y.piyo
FROM (
SELECT A.id, A.hoge, A.piyo
FROM A
UNION ALL 
SELECT B.a_id, "", B.piyo
FROM B
)Y
```

### ■ 現状取得結果

```
id　hoge　piyo
```

### ■ 希望取得結果

```
increment_id　id　hoge　piyo
```

### ■ やりたいこと

- `UNION ALL` する際、結果に `increment_id` カラムを新たに追加したい
- `increment_id` カラム … レコード順に+1

### ■ 背景

- 後で `GROUP_CONCAT` する際、使用したいので

Answer (score 3, accepted):

stackoverflow.com の方に [それっぽい回答](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094466/generate-serial-number-in-mysql-query/11096550#11096550) がありました。

```
SELECT
  @id:=@id+1 increment_id,
  Y.id,
  Y.hoge,
  Y.piyo
FROM 
  (select @id:=0) as id,
  (
    SELECT A.id, A.hoge, A.piyo FROM A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT B.a_id, "", B.piyo FROM B
  ) Y;
```

([実行結果](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e50a3/1))

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。おかげでうまくいきました。大変参考になりましたー

Comment: 下で別回答として、 MySQL 8.0 以上で利用できる、 window 関数の row_number() について記載しました。

Answer (score 0):

ohgaさんが投稿されてる
ユーザ変数を使う方法ですが

MySQLのマニュアルと
OracleACEのAketiJyuuzouさんとyoku0825さんと
日本オラクルの木村明治さんによると
MySQLのユーザ変数は評価順序が未定義です。
http://qiita.com/AketiJyuuzou/items/cced9b70cc714b382d98

なので、結果が保証されません。

具体的には、
(select @id:=0)
が一番最初に評価されることが保証されないので、
最終的な結果の連番は、
初回実行時は、nullが発生する可能性がありますし、
2回目以降は、歯抜けや重複が発生する可能性があります。

Comment: ユーザ変数の利用に注意が必要なことは同意しますが、歯抜けや重複は実際には起きないのではないでしょうか。
起きるとしたら SELECT の最中に FROM が評価された場合ですが、そんなエンジンが存在するとは考えにくいです。

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 8.0 以上で、 window 関数が導入されました。

```
SELECT row_number() OVER w AS increment_id, *
FROM tbl
WINDOW w AS ()
```

とすることで、今現在のデフォルトの返り値の順番に、行番号を採番することができます。

Answer (score -2):

rouさんの

> 歯抜けや重複は実際には起きないのではないでしょうか。

に対する返信です。
コメントで書こうとしたのですが、コメントって改行できないんですね。

起きるとしたら、こんなシナリオですか
もちろん他のシナリオもたくさんあるはずです。

MySQLのバグレポートで探せば、
バグではありません。と一蹴されてる例があるかもしれません。

```
１ インラインビュー(select ＠id:=0)の行数は1行だと分かった。
   ＠id:=0という、As指定のない無名列は、特に上位で使われてないようだ。
   (ユーザ変数@idがあるけど、先に評価しなきゃいけない仕様でないし・・・)
   次の２の処理と３の処理は、CPUが多いし、パラレルで処理しよう
２ クロスジョインしよう
３ ＠id:=0を評価しよう
```

要するに、クロスジョインにおいて、(select ＠id:=0)の行数は評価するけど
select句は、後回しに評価した場合です。